# Creating a function to search an array of strings for a certain word, and returning the element containing that word

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

The project I am currently trying to complete gives you an array (`coffees`). The goal is to output whether the coffee needs sugar, cream, or none, based on that if it is a light, medium, or dark roast. For example, `light colombian roast` should output `I'll have the light colombian roast and drink it black`. The current code I have does this correctly, except only for the first instance of light, medium, dark being found in the array coffees. Not too sure how to write my function to include all instances of the keyword being found, instead of stopping and storing only the index of the first string the word is in.

```
const coffees = [
    "light colombian roast", "hawaiian dark roast", "guatemalan blend medium roast",
    "dark madagascar blend", "jamaican dark blue", "jamaican medium roast",
    "salvador robusto light"
]

let output = ""

function searchStringInArray (str, strArray) {
    for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
        if(strArray[j].match(str)) {
        return j;
        }

    }
    return -1;
}

for (const coffee of coffees) {
    if (coffee.includes("light")) {  
        let i;
        i = searchStringInArray('light', coffees);
        output += `I'll have the ${coffees[i]} and drink it black`
    }
    else if (coffee.includes("medium")) {
        let k;
        k = searchStringInArray('medium', coffees);
        output += `I'll have the ${coffees[k]} and add cream only`
    }
    else if (coffee.includes("dark")) {
        let n;
        n = searchStringInArray('dark', coffees);
        output += `I'll have the ${coffees[n]} and add cream and sugar`
    }
    output += "\n"
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: match searches with a regular expression. Your first element starts with "light" and that's why it finds it but not the others.  Also, you don't need to search the entire array, you're already looping through each index in your FOR statement.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the first time I read it, ignore my first comment. Are you trying to group the different blends together? I don't get why you're searching in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making it too complicated unless I'm missing a step in what you're trying to do. You already loop through each coffee, no need to look it back up again.

```
for (const coffee of coffees) {
    if (coffee.includes("light")) {  
        output += `I'll have the ${coffee} and drink it black`
    }
    else if (coffee.includes("medium")) {
        output += `I'll have the ${coffee} and add cream only`
    }
    else if (coffee.includes("dark")) {

        output += `I'll have the ${coffee} and add cream and sugar`
    }
    output += "\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the logic too complex you can simply achieve it via using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) along with [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement for better performance as compare to multiple if/else clause.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const coffees = [
  "light colombian roast", "hawaiian dark roast", "guatemalan blend medium roast",
  "dark madagascar blend", "jamaican dark blue", "jamaican medium roast",
  "salvador robusto light"
];

const output = coffees.map(coffee => {
    switch(true) {
      case (/light/i.test(coffee)):
        str = `I'll have the ${coffee} and drink it black`
        break;
      case (/medium/i.test(coffee)):
        str = `I'll have the ${coffee} and add cream only`
        break;
      case (/dark/i.test(coffee)):
        str = `I'll have the ${coffee} and add cream and sugar`
        break;
    }
  return str;
});


console.log(output);
```